# Why do I get Error 2042 in VBA Evaluate INDEX/MATCH?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, evaluate

I asked for advice everywhere but with no help so far!

```
= Evaluate("INDEX(TEMPDB!E" & lrCHIIMPORT2 + 1 & ":E" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & ", 
 MATCH(STATIONS!B" & RARTSTAT3 & "& STATIONS!" & matchARTIST & "1, TEMPDB!C" & 
 lrCHIIMPORT2 + 1 & ":C" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & " & TEMPDB!A" & lrCHIIMPORT2 + 1 & 
 ":A" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & "))")
```

I get

> Error 2042

Both criteria is STRING, output is INTEGER or STRING!

Comment: You get it because somewhere in your formula you try to access a cell or a constant that is `#N/A`.

Comment: I believe your problem could possibly be stemming from this part of the formula: `STATIONS!B" & RARTSTAT3 & "& STATIONS!" & matchARTIST & "1`. Change to: `STATIONS!B1& STATIONS!" & matchARTIST & RARTSTAT3"` and see if that works. I'm not entirely sure but give it a try.

Comment: @waka I thought it too, but criteria and cell from criteria range have normal values - STRINGS in this case! CRITERIA1: KJLU and CRITERIA2: RC-IO. In range I can clearly see that those values exist and they are exactly the same so it should be found and returned (not values but INDEX of E:E column)

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Unfortunately this can't help since it would reffer always to cell B1 in STATIONS tab and actually must reffer to dynamic range... In one loop B2, in second B3, third B4 and so on.... Thnx anyway!

Comment: @IvanKočiš Oh, duh. Yea you're right, nevermind, I was thinking that it was a cell range, not concatenating. Ignore me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheets("STATIONS").Evaluate("INDEX(TEMPDB!E" & lrCHIIMPORT2 + 1 & ":E" & 
lr3CHIMPORT2 & ", MATCH(STATIONS!B" & RARTSTAT3 & "& STATIONS!" & matchARTIST 
& "1, TEMPDB!C" & lrCHIIMPORT2 + 1 & ":C" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & " & TEMPDB!A" & 
lrCHIIMPORT2 + 1 & ":A" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & ",0))")
```

i can't believe... Just FALSE on the end...!